# custom datatype - date and time

Tags: xml, xsd, type-conversion

I've been looking all over how to built your own custom datetime datatype.

I need it to be in this format : dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

can you help me ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not a good idea. XML is for storing data in a standard universal way not to include presentation so it would be wiser to stick with the existing standard datetime datatype defined in the spec for XML schema.  If you need the date in a different format for presentation or for storing in a database you should perform that transformation in whatever language you are using to parse the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I was think that create "custom datetime datatype" for XML schema too.

But my case format is "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm".

```
<xsd:simpleType name="custom.datetime">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="(\d{1,4}/((0[13578]|1[02])/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])|(0[469]|11)/(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)|02/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|((\d{0,2}((0[48]|[2468][048])|[13579][26]))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])00)/02/29) ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```